# In C#, the MongoDB mapping DateTime went wrong

Tags: c#, mongodb

The insert is fine. However, the query will fail to convert to DateTime. Some will fail to convert to DateTime properly. The error is shown below

An error occurred while deserializing the StartDateTime property of class AHF.AnXinPai.DataModels.MongoEntities.Mongo_ZeroBidPromotionProduct: String '2020-08-12 04:02:13.347' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My Entity
public System.Int64 CreateAdminUserID { get; set; }

```
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public System.DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public System.DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }

    public System.Int32 OnlieTime { get; set; }
```

Ask the great god to solve it

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to interpret a string as a timestamp. My guess is you stored some times as strings in the database.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I updated my DateTime to a String using a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your question I assume we're dealing with string dates within the database.

So your documents look something like the following

```js
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f356e3d7a8de29bc751009d"),
    "StartDateTime" : "2020-08-12T04:02:13.347",
    "EndDateTime" : "2020-08-12T04:02:13.347"
}
```

You can then add an extra property to your BsonDateTimeOptions attribute on the property of `Representation` of `String` which will make the driver serialise and deserialise in to a string.

```cs
public class Data
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local, Representation = BsonType.String)]
    public System.DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local, Representation = BsonType.String)]
    public System.DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```